# How can I override ChildActionOnly attribute set on controller class for a particular method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have ChildActionOnly set on the class of a controller called 'NavController'.  I'd like one of the methods to be exposed and not be restricted by the ChildActionOnly attribute.  How can I do that?

Here's a glimpse of the controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public class NavController : Controller
{
    [NotChildActionOnly] //does something like this exist natively in asp.net Mvc?
    public ActionResult GetSomething()
    {
        return View()
    }
}
```

If the 'NotChildActionOnly' attribute doesn't exist natively then I'll go down the path of writing a custom action filter such as 'OverridableChildActionOnly(enable/disable)' but I wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel.